# Number of positive integral solutions of a polynomial inequation

Tags: functions

The question : Let $f(x)=30-2x-x^3$. Find the number of positive integral values of $x$ which satisfies $f(f(f(x))))>f(f(-x))$.

When I looked at this problem I noticed that the question talks about positive integers and hence for all $ x \gt 0$, $f(x)$ is less than $30$.
Replacing $ x $ by $ –x $ in the question we get $f(x)+f(-x)=60$.
Now replacing $x$ by $f(x)$ we get $f(f(x))+f(-f(x))=60$.
Also it can be seen that  $f(-x) \gt -f(x)
$
So $f(f(x))+f(f(-x)) \gt 60$ after reaching at this inequality I seemed to get nothing. Any help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a decreasing function. So $$f(f(x))>f(f(-x))$$ if and only if $$f(x)<f(-x)$$ if and only if $$x>-x$$ which is true for *all* positive $x$.

---

In a comment to another answer you appear to say that the inequality to solve is actually $$f(f(f(x)))>f(f(-x))$$ In that case the same logic tells you this is true if and only if 
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&>-x\\ 
30-2x-x^3&>-x\\
30-x-x^3&>0\\
(3-x)(10+3x+x^2)&>0
\end{align}$$

Since $10+3x+x^2$ is positive for all $x$, this only true for positive $x$ when $x=1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 0):

if we have $f(x)=30-2x-x^3$ then we get $f(-x)=30+2x+x^3$ and you must solve
$$30-2(30-2x-x^3)-(30-2x-x^3)^3>30-2(30+2x+x^3)-(30+2x+x^3)$$
can you simplify this?

Comment: i have just edited the question. by mistake the question was typed as f(f(x))>f(f(-x)).but the real question is f(f(f(x)))>f(f(-x))

Comment: @shubham What you say in this comment still does not match the question.

Comment: I have corrected the question. But your attempts are now meaningless. Do you intend to cancel them ?